Convert entire web page into pdf file
I am trying to convert below web page into PDF document using .NET:
https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm
Can someone tell me how to do it? I tried PDFsharp but it's creating PDF with url link:
        Byte[] res = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf("https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm", PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
            pdf.Save(ms);
            res = ms.ToArray();
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("TestPDF.pdf", res);


Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597103/generate-pdf-based-on-html-code-itextsharp-pdfsharp/31109987#31109987

Please allow me to share my test result below. I did a lot of work. To summarize here, PDFsharp has an extension which could convert html string to pdf file, but we can't simplely obtain the html response from url then convert the response to string and start the convertion, this library might not be so powerful to handle complex html content. We might need another tool. But before all these tasks, we need to make sur ethe target url can be accessed via our codes, as the website can be reached in browser directly, but will give 403 error when we use codes to visit it like visit an API.

That page contains an IFRAME. You need to use the IFRAME's URL to retrieve the actual content. If you inspect the page using your browser's Dev Tools you'll see the IFRAME's src is /ixviewer/ix.html?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm, so the full URL should be https://www.sec.gov/ixviewer/ix.html?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm

That said, the site itself may prevent access by bots by eg, checking the Agent header to see whether it matches a normal browser or not.

Thanks for your tip. I do used https://www.sec.gov/ixviewer/ix.html?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm in my test but 403. By the way, in my API calling extension, when I added user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 I can get the html content as the response, but even if I added it into my httpclient request, I still get 403 error.

The menu on that site has a simple "View as html" entry. That one should be usable to translate to pdf.

Those are XBRL documents (have their own structure) and thus not a "Web" page in the conventional format. Pages are not a conventional size thus that example should be 77 pages.
There are several User Agent security checks to ensure you are simply using a browser in the conventional fashion E.G. you or your puppet.
To Print as a web page you need to open that page as HTML by remove the ix
https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm
becomes
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm
and simply then print it as HTML2PDF using save as PDF CTRL + P. you can do that with say VBA or a mouse.
The PDF is instantly available as 85 pages.  HOWEVER NOTE it should be 77 pages (as stated) and for that you need to set scale to 90%


My argument is if you navigated to initially "find that page" and calculate the scalar, you need! Then simply press CTRL + P yourself and no need for programming or auto-authorisation.

I'm afraid none of the libraries could achieve your requirement directly as we will get 403 error when we visit the url through httpclient or tools like postman.

Before I have a test using Polybioz.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Core to convert html string to PDF which could work, this time I tried to get html content by httpclient but getting 403 error. So that I copied the html response from browser for test purpose, but it failed again, maybe it's due to the html content is too complex.
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.sec.gov/ixviewer/ix.html?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm");
string HtmlContent = "";
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
    HtmlContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}


Next I went to PuppeteerSharp and have a try with package <PackageReference Include="PuppeteerSharp" Version="20.0.2" /> and codes below.
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();
using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true });
using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync("https://www.sec.gov/ixviewer/ix.html?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/55242/000005524224000055/kmt-20240630.htm");
await page.PdfAsync(@"C:\example.pdf", new PdfOptions
{
    Format = PaperFormat.A4
});

The codes above do generate a pdf file, but the content is like below, and it might indicate that our access against the security policy of the website.

But if I changed the URL to https://www.google.com/, it worked well.

